# Почему точь-в-точь через дефис?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Почему точь-в-точь через дефис?

Answer (score 2):

ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ ---наречие. Оно  возникло из сочетания древнего имени существительного ТЪЧЬ (производного от основы ТЪК-, выступающей в ТЪКАТИ, ТЪКНОУТИ ---совр. ТКАТЬ, ТКНУТЬ) . От этого имени существительного образовано и слово ТЪЧ+ЬК+(а) - совр. ТОЧКА. 
Слово ТОЧЬ в современном русском языке не употребляется, поэтому раздельно писаться не может, оно сохранилось лишь в наречии ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ,это точно наречие, а не сущ.+существительное с предлогом.Точь (во что? )в точь не скажешь. В то же время еще ощущаются  связи со словом ТОЧКА, правда слабые. Чувствуется и наличие В -бывшего предлога со значением "направление куда-н. "Наличие предлога указывает на остатки грамматического значения существительного- слитно нельзя. Раздельно нельзя, слитно нельзя. Отсюда и дефисное, т. е. полуслитное написание этого наречия.

Вот "точка в точку" -повторение слова ТОЧКА в разных падежных формах с предлогом В. Оно сохраняет морфологическую принадлежность к разряду имен существительных (точка во что?- в точку), тем более что слово употребляется в современном русском языке не только в этом сочетании, но и совершенно свободно, а В сохраняет принадлежность к предлогу.

Answer (score 2):

1. В русском языке встречается значительное количество наречий, которые не употребляются без предлога/приставки, но пишутся раздельно, например:до зарезу, до упаду, без прОсыпа, без ведома, без умолку, без устали, на дыбы, на попятную, на побегушках, на убой,  с лихвой, с ведома, во всеуслышание, во всеоружии,  по старинке. В этом случае фактор наличия падежного управления оказался сильнее исходного фактора.
2. А теперь попробуем выбрать форму написания для названного наречия точь-в-точь. Слитное написание трех слов в одно абсолютно не читается, да и фактор падежного управления присутствует. Но и  раздельное написание словосочетания  - слишком смелое решение, учитывая влияния основного фактора. Поэтому используется промежуточная форма - это еще не слово, но уже не словосочетание.

Comment: Да,именно так: до зарезу - фактор наличия падежного управления, т.е.существительного  нет, а грамматическая связь существительного осталась, а пока она есть, можно сказать до чего? - до зарезу. Это НАРЕЧНОЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ= сущ.+ предлог, а не окончательно наречие.Наречие как часть речи ещё пока не оформилось окончательно.

Comment: Иногда говорят: "Устал в(?)у(?)смерть". А тут как быть? "Ву" не предлог, слова "усмерть" нет. Что делать? Или это разговорное?

Comment: Падежное управление здесь присутствует - винительный падеж указывает общее направление процесса. Но предлог ВО выступает в форме ВУ, которая будет прецедентной для письма, поэтому пишем слитно.

Comment: Конечно,  разговорное.

Comment: Разговорные слова тоже иногда приходится записывать, так что все они имеют письменную форму.